# Julia: How do I use args... in macros?

Tags: macros, julia

Say I want

```
@fn a :b :c
```

to expand to

```
gn(a, :b, :c)
```

and currently I am writing it as

```
macro fn(x, args...)
  esc(:(gn($x, $args...)))
end
```

which doesn't seem to work.

How do I expand the `args...` is a macro as is?

Comment: This is a duplicate of a second question by the same user and should be closed or deleted.

Comment: It's not a dup. this is about args and the other is about kwargs

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap `args...` in `$` or it will interpolate `args` and then `...`

```
macro fn(x, args...)
  esc(:(gn($x, $(args...))))
end
```

Comment: Note that this is special syntax of interpolation, that will expand to `Expr(:call, :gn, x, args...)` So it makes sense everywhere where an `Expr` expects a sequence of forms: blocks, arguments, indices, vectors, and more.